# What are private packages in the ubuntu Repository?

Tags: repository, packaging, software-sources, development, versions

[image]

I see private packages in the Repos from time to time. What exactly does having a package labelled private delineate? What would I need it for?

Comment: The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors...Could you add the image to the question?

Comment: @Bruni Works for me... Even tried it in another browser.

Answer (score 1):

These are packages contain qt's private headers, Debian states that you should use them at your own risk and if you take a look at their source code you will see a lot of comments like:

```
//
//  W A R N I N G
//  -------------
//
// This file is not part of the Qt API.  It exists for the convenience
// of other Qt classes.  This header file may change from version to
// version without notice, or even be removed.
//
// We mean it.
//
```

to inspect the source yourself:

```
apt-get download package-name
dpkg-deb --extract package-name.deb .
```

There are other private packages too, e.g:

```
apt-cache search --names-only private
```

let's check [digikam-private-libs](https://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/digikam-private-libs), and from [Debian's description](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/digikam-private-libs):

> This has no use for anything else than digikam, since the libraries are installed in a private library path.

Comment: Is it just Qt packages that have private headers?

Comment: Check my update ;)

Comment: I am still a bit lost as to the point or usefulness of private headers.

Comment: From the last quote I guess they're just meant to be used by their own project not others...

Comment: so basically, it varies between packages? I think I recall the Qt private packages as being useful for compiling your own version of QtCreator. I wasnt sure, and figured that I would ask to see if there is some convention with packages and labelling them private.

Comment: Seems that could be the case, [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140387/what-is-purpose-of-p-h-files). However I guess this question gets a better and more specific answer at https://stackoverflow.com .